# Incorrect calculations of averages

Tags: c

I have this super simple code for calculating averages of given even and odd numbers, until the user gives 0. (I would use for loop but we can't).
I'm having a really strange problem with program rounding results like 25/2 is 2.00000. Sorry if this question is stupid but I just can't find a problem.
What am I doing completely wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funkcja()
{
    int sumaNiep = 0;
    int sumaPa = 0;
    int userInput = 1;
    int i = 0;

    while(userInput != 0)
    {
        //wprow zmiennej
        printf("%d. Podaj calkowita liczbe: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &userInput);

        //jesli parzysta
        if (userInput % 2 == 0)
        {
            sumaPa += userInput;
        } else {
            sumaNiep += userInput;
        }
        i++;
    }

    double sredniaNiep = sumaNiep/(i-1);
    double sredniaPa = sumaPa/(i-1);

    printf("\nsrednia parzysta %d / %d : %lf", sumaPa, i, sredniaPa);
    printf("\nsrednia parzysta %d / %d : %lf", sumaNiep, i, sredniaNiep);

}


int main()
{
    funkcja();
}
```

Comment: integer division: sumaNiep/(i-1)

Comment: There is no double rounding here. “Double rounding” refers to a situation in which a number is rounded twice, once to an intermediate format and once to a final format, particularly when there is a possibility the result of the two roundings may differ from the result of rounding once directly to the final format. The problems in this code were caused by failing to count the numbers of odd and even numbers separately and by using integer division where floating-point division is needed. Neither of those involves double rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do an integer division at the end.

You should break out of the loop if the user enters `0` and make at least one operand a `double` when you do the division. You also need to count the number of evens and odds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funkcja() {
    int sumaNiep = 0;
    int sumaPa = 0;
    int userInput = 1;
    int iPa = 0;
    int iNiep = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(1) {
        printf("%d. Podaj calkowita liczbe: ", ++i);
        if(scanf(" %d", &userInput) != 1 || userInput == 0) break; // break out

        // jesli parzysta
        if(userInput % 2 == 0) {
            sumaPa += userInput;
            ++iPa;                  // count evens
        } else {
            sumaNiep += userInput;
            ++iNiep;                // count odds
        }
    }
    if(iPa) { // avoid div by zero
        double sredniaPa = (double)sumaPa / iPa;       // double div
        printf("srednia parzysta %d / %d : %lf\n", sumaPa, iPa, sredniaPa);
    }
    if(iNiep) { // avoid div by zero
        double sredniaNiep = (double)sumaNiep / iNiep; // double div
        printf("srednia parzysta %d / %d : %lf\n", sumaNiep, iNiep, sredniaNiep);
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't the problem here, in the last printf the sum and the counter are right. The double div isn't solving this either

Comment: @KarolGral Ok, I added that part too

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I divided by the number of all digits (odd and even) to calculate both averages. Here is improved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funkcja()
{
    int sumaNiep = 0;
    int sumaPa = 0;
    int userInput = 1;
    int i_p = 0, i_np = 0;

    while(userInput != 0)
    {
        //wprow zmiennej
        printf("%d. Podaj calkowita liczbe: ", i_p+i_np+1);
        scanf("%d", &userInput);

        //jesli parzysta
        if (userInput % 2 == 0)
        {
            sumaPa += userInput;
            if (userInput != 0)
            {
                 i_p++;
            }
        } else {
            sumaNiep += userInput;
            i_np++;
        }


    }

    if (i_np != 0)
    {
        double sredniaNiep = sumaNiep/(i_np);
        printf("\nSrednia nieparzysta %d / %d : %lf", sumaNiep, i_np, sredniaNiep);

    }
    if (i_p != 0)
    {
        double sredniaPa = sumaPa/(i_p);
        printf("\nSrednia parzysta %d / %d : %lf", sumaPa, i_p, sredniaPa);
    }


}


int main()
{
    funkcja();
}
```

Comment: Note that without a cast of one of the operands in the divisions, you will not get fractions in the result so making `sredniaNiep` and `sredniaPa` `double`s serves no purpose. You should also check that `scanf` succeeds.